# How do I filter for rows in a Pandas dataframe based on a column that has list as values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe where one of the columns stores lists of string literals. For example, my data looks like the following.

```
field1, field2
x1, ['tag1', 'tag2']
x2, ['tag1', 'tag3']
```

I want to get only the records in this dataframe whose `field2` list contains `tag1` or `tag2`. So, in the example above, only the record where `field1=x1` should be returned.

How can I do this filtering on a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Do you mean `tag1` and `tag2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for `tag2` in the list of `field2`. Using [.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), you can achieve this.

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: 'tag2' in x['field2'],axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
    field1  field2
0   x1      [tag1, tag2]
```